# Textboxes and Checkboxes are created in for loop, how to load value automatically in textbox when the corresponding checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I am doing an .NET MVC project, there i am running a *for* loop to create n number of textboxes and checkboxes, I want to fill data in textbox when corresponding checkbox is checked. Since all the textboxes and the checkboxes have same ID and Name, I am facing problem.

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{                   
    <input type="checkbox" name="BooksToCart" id="BooksToCart" value="@item.BookId">
    <input type="number" name="NoBooksToCart" id="NoBooksToCart">
}
```

I would also like the javascript code. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like valid razor code to me.

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for how to correctly generate form controls for a collection

Comment: "Since all the textboxes and the checkboxes have same ID and Name, I am facing problem". Yes you are, Id's **must** be unique. Are you open to using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You can make different id of text box and check box as below

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <input type="checkbox" name="BooksToCart" id="BooksToCart-@item.BookId"    value="@item.BookId">
  <input type="number" name="NoBooksToCart" id="NoBooksToCart-@item.BookId">
}
```